# Flutter showGeneralDialog with Slide and Fade animations

Tags: flutter

I have the following dialog. It has Slide Transition when it pops up on the screen and when it is being dismissed. Along with it, I also use Fade Transition for the background when dialog is showed or closed.

```
      showGeneralDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        barrierLabel: '',
        barrierColor: kModalBackgroundColor,
        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
        pageBuilder: (ctx, anim1, anim2) {
          return DismissibleModalWidget();
        },
        transitionBuilder: (ctx, anim1, anim2, child) {
          return SlideTransition(
            position: Tween(begin: Offset(0, 1), end: Offset(0, 0)).animate(anim1),
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 8 * anim1.value, sigmaY: 8 * anim1.value),
              child: FadeTransition(
                opacity: anim1,
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        context: context,
      );
```

Widget `DismissibleModalWidget`

```
class DismissibleModalWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DismissibleModalWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: const Key('dismissible'),
      direction: DismissDirection.vertical,
      onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      child: Material(
      .....
```

**What the code does now**

`SlideTransition` works before `FadeTransition`, meaning that first the dialog will appear on the screen, then the fade transition will start to work. Same when I drag down the dialog to dismiss it, only after the dialog disappeared completely from the screen, fade will start animation from the blurred screen.

**What I want to achieve**

I would like to make both of these transitions to work together. Meaning as slide animation of the dialog is progress, so is fade transition of the background. When I want to drag down the dialog to dismiss it, the fade will start working and the more I drag down the dialog, the less blurred the background will be so that as soon as dialog completely disappeared, the background is back to normal.

Comment: [StaggeredAnimations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations) might help you!

Comment: @gtxtreme I had a look there as well, the thing I cannot figure out is whether I need a ```Tween``` for ```ImageFilter.blur``` and if I had one, how would it work since even now I use the same Animation```anim1``` for both slide and fade transitions.